# Delegate not being called when KVO SKSpriteNode's Position (Key Value Observing of CGPoint)

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

Have tried:

```
[self.hero addObserver:self 
            forKeyPath:@"position.x"
               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
               context:nil];
```

as well as:

```
KeyPath:@"position"
```

and neither are calling

```
 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                       ofObject:(id)object 
                         change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                        context:(void *)context
```

Comment: where observeValueForKeyPath is located?  is it in same class where u called?

Comment: self.hero is a SKSpriteNode, SKSpriteNode inherits from SKNode which has a position property. 'position' is a property on self.hero's superclass

Comment: Have you tried observing `@"position"` instead of `@"position.x"`?